# Scanf и несанкционированный перенос строки с++

Tags: qt, c++

Добрый день.. Проблема:

```
class AAddInvestor: public action
{
public:
    AAddInvestor(db *_base){base=_base;}
    std::string ActionName(){return "Add investor";}
    void doit()
    {
        utl::ClearConsole();
        //justaman * tempinvestor=new justaman;
        std::string tname;
        float tmoney;

        printf("Enter name:");
        scanf("\n\0%[A-z]",tname.c_str());
        printf("Enter money:");
        scanf("\n\0%[0-9]",tmoney);

        //tempinvestor->Name(tname);
        //tempinvestor->AllMoney(tmoney);

        //base->add_investor(tempinvestor);

    }
 private: db *base;
};
```

После вывода "Enter name:" в консоли появляется перенос строки:

```
Enter name:

123
```

Как от него избавиться, ума не приложу. Необходимо, чтобы каретка для ввода была сразу после двоеточия. Испробовал [это](http://cppstudy.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/cin-get-and-co/)

не помогло =\

Проблема локализовалась здесь:

```
#define KEYDOWN(vk_code) \
((GetAsyncKeyState(vk_code) & 0x8000) ? 1 : 0)
#define KEYUP(vk_code) \
((GetAsyncKeyState(vk_code) & 0x8000) ? 0 : 1)

void mainmenu::choose()
{
   current(0);
    do{
        if (KEYDOWN(VK_UP))
            if (current()>borderup()){utl::KeyReleased(VK_UP);current()--;draw_menu();}
        if (KEYDOWN(VK_DOWN))
            if (current()<borderdown()) {utl::KeyReleased(VK_DOWN);current()++; draw_menu();}

    }while(!KEYDOWN(VK_RETURN));

    utl::KeyReleased(VK_RETURN);
    actions[current()]->doit();
}
```

Теперь вопрос: как очистить или закрыть на время поток ввода? ибо функция GetAsyncKeyState съедает прерывание, а буферизированный поток засоряется и не поддается flush..

Проблема решена банально.. решение = (нужная_строка&&нужное_место).
Пришлось считывать весь поток после каждого воровства прерывания(вызова функции choose()).

**[РЕШЕНИЕ!](https://yadi.sk/d/ND4jd0cAWTmVm)** Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: Возможно такие форматы `scanf`-а это что-то специфически виндузовое (я с такими не знаком), но IMHO в любом случае при вводе `float` надо передавать **адрес** пременной, да и чтение внутрь `string` на мой взгляд не лучшая идея.

--

Попробуйте для начала что-нибудь попроще:

    char tn[100], done = 0;
    float tmoney;

    do {
      printf("Enter name: ");
      if (scanf("%[A-z]", tn) == 1) {
        printf("Enter money: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &tmoney) == 1) {
           done = 1; break;
        }
      }
      if (feof(stdin))
        break;
      ...

места мало...

Comment: (продолжение)

      fgets(tn, 100, stdin); // clear bad input
      puts("Invalid input. Try again");
    } while (1);

    if (done) {
      printf ("Name: [%s] money: %f\n", tn, tmoney);
      // на самом деле, та обработка, которая Вам нужна
    }

Comment: Спасибо за Сделал как вы сказали и стало видно насколько засоряется stdin:

Enter name:
Invalid input. Try again
Enter name:
Invalid input. Try again
Enter name:123

Благодаря вам, я могу отсеять хлам, но очень хотелось бы понять откуда он берется

Comment: @kernelplv: 1) Если вы пишете на C++, пользуйтесь `cin <<`, а не `printf`. Лучше оставаться в рамках одного языка, если на то нет серьёзных причин.

2) Вы не имеете права использовать `tname.c_str()` для записи! `string` имеет право выдать вам временную копию данных. Снова-таки, пользуйтесь потоковым вводом, он лучше предназначен для работы с C++-типами.

Comment: перешел на printf и scanf потому что с cin и cout было тоже самое

Comment: Проблем с правильностью ввода строки нет. Проблема только в лишнем переносе строки.
Мне нужно, чтобы каретка была непосредственно после двоеточия, сразу после фразы "Enter name:". Но она убегает на строку, а то и две вперед

Comment: @kernelplv: `sizeof(stdin)`?? Что-то я сомневаюсь в правильности этого кода.

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте scanf никогда, кроме мелких случаев в полностью контролируемом окружении.

```
#include <stdlib.h>     // strtod
#include <stdio.h>      // fflush, fgets, printf

double input_float(void)
{
    static char buf[20]; // 19 знаков хватит?
    double n;
    char* end;
    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin); // переполнение буфера невозможно
        n = strtod(buf, &end);
    } while( end == buf ); // если не было обработано ни одного символа
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    double n;
    do {
        n = input_float(); // попробуйте ввести что-нибудь некорректное
        printf("f = %f\n", n);
    } while( n != 0.0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, для ввода float очень полено, но у меня проблема как раз с вводом строки. strtod, к сожалению, здесь никак не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обычный потоковый ввод.

Вот вам тестовый код:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename CHAR>
bool stoa(const basic_string< CHAR, char_traits<CHAR>, allocator<CHAR> >& s, T& t)
{
    basic_istringstream< CHAR, char_traits<CHAR>, allocator<CHAR> > iss(s);
    return !!(iss >> t);
}

template <typename T, typename CHAR>
bool input(basic_istream< CHAR, char_traits<CHAR> >& s, T& t)
{
    basic_string< CHAR, char_traits<CHAR>, allocator<CHAR> > buffer;
    getline(s, buffer);
    return stoa(buffer, t);
}

bool all_letters_or_space(string s)
{
    for (auto c : s)
        if (!isalpha(c) && !isspace(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string name;
    float money;

    cout << "Enter name: ";
    while (!getline(cin, name) || !all_letters_or_space(name))
        cout << "Wrong input, enter name: ";

    cout << "Enter money: ";
    while (!input(cin, money))
        cout << "Wrong input, enter money: ";

    cout << "Finally: name = " << name << ", money = " << money << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Тестовый прогон:

> Enter name: John 2
> Wrong input, enter name: John Doe
> Enter money: error
> Wrong input, enter money: 0.02
> Finally: name = John Doe, money = 0.02.

---

В вашем коде undefined behaviour, так как `.c_str()` [возвращает `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: получается так
https://yadi.sk/d/la6x64QtWTEvb
никак не могу понять, откуда берутся эти переносы

Comment: @kernelplv: У вас наверняка что-то осталось в input buffer'е. Думаю, там невычитанный Enter.

Попробуйте выкинуть или исправить предыдущий код, ошибка там. В качестве временной заплатки можете попробовать

    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

перед `cout << "Enter name: ";`

Comment: сделал с вашей заплаткой. получилось так https://yadi.sk/d/CTVU2uCxWTJFA

Comment: @kernelplv: Попробуйте код, который приведён в ответе. Если этот код функционирует как надо, значит, проблема вашей программы где-то до него. Посмотрите, что приходит в `name` после вызова `getline`. Попробуйте `ignore` несколько раз подряд, кто знает, что у вас в буфере.

В любом случае проблема в предыдущем коде. Сконструируйте [_минимальный_ законченный самодостаточный компилируемый пример](http://sscce.org/), который воспроизводит вашу ошибку, тогда нам будет легче понять суть проблемы.

Comment: удалость локализовать ошибку. если идти напрямую без цикла сразу к doit(), то никаких переносов нет. Вероятно VK_RETURN проскакивает каким то образом
https://yadi.sk/d/x_htttX5WTN2j
https://yadi.sk/d/S4nuP_JEWTLNR

Comment: @kernelplv: Ох. `GetAsyncKeyState` и прочее WinAPI, прямой доступ к клавиатуре.

Неудивительно, что оно не работает: наверняка анализ нажатия клавиш оставляет их в stdin. Вы смешиваете два совершенно различных подхода к управлению клавиатурой — стандартный буферизованный поток и почти прямой доступ к аппаратуре.

Вам придётся подобрать метод полного сброса буфера ввода.

Но лучше выбрать только один из методов доступа, и придерживаться его. Иначе, боюсь, проблем в будущем (и многочисленных костылей в настоящем) не избежать.

Comment: я не нашел другого способа выйти из цикла по enter, без постоянной остановки цикла ради проверки. должен же быть способ почистить буфер

Comment: @kernelplv: Если вам нужен низкоуровневый метод небуферизованного управления клавиатурой (например, опрос того, нажата ли клавиша в данный момент), лучше перейти полностью на чтение клавиатуры «вручную» посимвольно, и конвертацию в нужные типы из строк (см. функцию `stoa`). Иначе вам придётся всё время синхронизировать высокоуровневое и низкоуровневое состояние ввода, что далеко не комильфо.